# ASP.NET C# Exception Handling with Nido

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, error-handling

I am using [Nido](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830384/ASP-NET-Csharp-Development-with-Nido-Framework-for) Framework to develop my ASP.NET Web Application. It has a default mode to log all errors occurred in back end layer. But now I want to handle page level exceptions and log them as well. Can I use the same framework to do that or do I have to find some other means?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log errors in a class, then you can derive that class from '**LoggerBase**' as below do exception logging..

```
public class PaymentGatewayWrapper : LoggerBase
{
    protected override Type LogPrefix
    {
        get { return this.GetType(); }
    }

    public void ProcessPayment(Object paymentInfo, Object customer,
    Guid orderGuid, ref Object processPaymentResult)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Required operational level code
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            this.LogError("Error processing payment", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

However if you want to do this via a web page. You will don't have the option to derive it from a custom class. Then you can take another path as below...

```
new LogManager(this.GetType()).LogError("This is a test error", ex);
```

Additional references

- [Gain Coding Speed with Nido (FREE) Framework .NET/ C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/698486/Introduction-to-Nido-FREE-Framework-NET-Csharp)
- [ASP.NET/C# Development with Nido Framework for Dummies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/830384/ASP-NET-Csharp-Development-with-Nido-Framework-for)